# How can I display different icons for same file extension

Tags: windows, icons

Visual Studio has *.SLN files for 2008, and 2010.

In explorer, the icon associated with the file is based on the version somehow. I was always under the impression that the associated icon just looked at the extension, but obviously there is more going on.

I'm asking on stack overflow as a developer - for my application, but if you feel this belongs on another forum, I'm happy to move the discussion elsewhere.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln\ShellEx\IconHandler`. The icon is handled by a shell extension, not the usual way with a `DefaultIcon`.

MSDN's [Creating Icon Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144122%28VS.85%29.aspx) page shows you how to create the shell extension DLL that provides the icons.

Answer (score 1):

I found some Delphi code at [http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3285.asp](http://web.archive.org/web/20080723234358/http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3285.asp) that seems to do the job.  Maybe this can give you some inspiration.

EDIT: site does not exist anymore, using web.archive.org provided by @samir105

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20080723234358/http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3285.asp